# Why giving me empty file when adding a class in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, class, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to add a class to my model in visual studio ultimate 2013, so here is how i do it, right click on models>add>class>in visual C# I choose Class>then I click add, here a message appears to me with a drop down menu asking me to chose the Encoding, when I open the drop down menu , it brings me a lot of options, I chose anything , and still gives me a blank file, if I don't choose anything and press cancel, it just gives me a blank text file.
Any Idea why this happening?

Comment: Sounds like your item template is broken - first thing to try would be running *Repair* for your VS installation - unless you feel comfortable [diving into the template files themselves](http://ericsowell.com/blog/2007/5/22/how-to-edit-visual-studio-templates).

Comment: I don't have the ItemTemplates folder inside the IDE! !

Comment: On a x64 System the path to look for is `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class` where `1033` may differ for your installed localized version.

Comment: ok good now i located the item templates, can someone take me through step by step on how to edit them, as I am new to c# and visual studio

Comment: If you are not familiar with this stuff I'd rather recommend trying to run *Repair*. However it cannot hurt if you just open the .cs file with a text editor of your choice. The linked blog should give you an idea what you can expect to see. Another thing to try would be to run Visual Studio as an Administrator to see if it's just a matter of permissions.